# API for rabbitmq-plugins?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

So you can get all sorts of information from the [management HTTP API](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_1/priv/www/api/index.html), but one thing that you **can't** get is a list of the plugins.

Typically you'd use `rabbitmq-plugins list` for this, but I need a list from within a python script.

Is there any way to query `rabbitmq-plugins` without having to make a shell call and then parse the output? Perhaps some sort of HTTP API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting it turns out that you CAN get the plugins through the management API, although it's a little bit of a roundabout way, and can only return enabled plugins (and not whether they were explicitly enabled). It solves my particular problem, however it would be great if there was a better way.

`/api/nodes` returns a list of nodes, which each will have an `applications` key which contains the plugins enabled on that node. For example,

```
{
"version": "3.5.1", 
"name": "rabbitmq_management_agent", 
"description": "RabbitMQ Management Agent"
},
```